# Swift AVKit aspect ratio not working correctly

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, avplayer, avkit

I want to surround the below PlayerView with a border. I want the video to scale to aspect ratio (it does) but when I draw the border around it, it seems like the PlayerView is formatted as a square...

```
PlayerView(forResource: "x", withExtension: "mp4")
    .scaledToFit()
    .frame(height: 200)
    .cornerRadius(20)
    .overlay(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 5)
    )

struct PlayerView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let forResource: String
    let withExtension: String
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<PlayerView>) {
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        return LoopingPlayerUIView(frame: .zero, forResource: forResource, withExtension: withExtension)
    }
}

class LoopingPlayerUIView: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    init(frame: CGRect, forResource: String, withExtension: String) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        // Load the resource -> h
        let fileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: forResource, withExtension: withExtension)!
        let asset = AVAsset(url: fileUrl)
        let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        // Setup the player
        let player = AVQueuePlayer()
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspect
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        // Create a new player looper with the queue player and template item
        playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: item)
        // Start the movie
        player.play()
    }
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg0kX.png